# Read data from DHT11 using ATmega32

Tags: atmega32

The problem is this:
I want to display on the LCD, the data transmitted by DHT11, but I fail to do so.

[Simulation on Proteus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOs37.png)

```
This is the main code: https://pastecode.io/s/nuw0hxkc 
LCD library: https://pastecode.io/s/xh93auwq 
DHT11 library: https://pastecode.io/s/7xma86jp
```

I don't understand where I'm wrong.
With the debugger we obtained these values for the variables:

```
I_RH=223
D_RH=225
I_Temp=225
D_Temp=225
CheckSum=225
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In the simulation I had to change CKSEL Fuses in Internal 8MHz.